# what are the good practices in handling kubectl context in scripts?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

My bash scripts with `kubectl` sometimes cause trouble when it changes context. After running the script user may accidentally end up make changes in wrong cluster. I would like to probe your wisdom when it comes to handling context in scripts.

Is it possible for the script to save old context and when done revert the old context back? (I thought about running `kubectl config get-contexts` find current context and set it back after script completes. But this may fail if user haven't saved contexts)

Other approach I am thinking is to save the value of KUBECONFIG env var, change it to a temp file, get credentials and restore the value when the script completes.

Before I go and reinvent the wheel I like to here how the power users are handling situation like this? Can you share your thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, I think it's problematic to depend implicitly on global state that may be arbitrarily updated by other processes and users.

Even with multiple configuration files, there's still opacity as to which cluster, user, namespace, context are being used.

For a single user, `kubectl`'s configuration file provides the convenience of not having to retype flags for every command and I think that should be it's sole purpose.

In scripts, I think it's preferable (clearer|self-documenting) to be explicit and to include either `--context` or `--cluster`, `--user` (and possibly `--namespace`) every time.

This said, it is also advisable to use variables rather than hard-coded values so there's still room for error.

```sh
kubectl delete deployment/primary-service

# vs

KUBECONFIG=sam-monday-morning-config.yaml \
kubectl delete deplopyment/primary-service

# vs

kubectl delete deployment/primary-service \
--cluster=test-cluster \
--namespace=test-namespace \
--user=test-user
```